# Start Application when Windows starts

Tags: vb.net

I searched and used the code from internet to do this but not get it done I'm using this code

```
Dim appstartup_path As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath)
    Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
    regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)

    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then

        regKey.SetValue("my_app", "app_path")
        regKey.Close()

    Else

        regKey.DeleteValue("my_app", False)

    End If
```

But getting error for object refrence is not set...!
so is this a right way do?

Or what else is the solution

Thnaks....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this right now, but it looks to me that the line

```
regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\...
```

contains a redundant `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` entry. `Registry.LocalMachine` already represents the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` folder. Any subfolder you wish to select should not contain it.

```
regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft...
```

should work.

Comment: Hi John,when do this then it is giving error "Requested registry access is not allowed".

Comment: Rahul, that means that at least your RegKey now has a valid registry key assigned (not null). Now you have a problem with access rights, which is not really my cup of tea. Access to the registry is limited by the Windows OS and depends on policies, user types, etc.

Comment: You must run the Program by Run As Administrator.

Comment: @Arwin Zhang i'm running program from Visual studio and I'm login from Administrator.So why it is giving me this error..?

Comment: @RahulShirphule Ok, i need to told to you, even your Account type is Admin, but your VS not exactly still in administrator. If not believe, try moving your Project folder to C:\Program Files\ and open it, you will be ask to active VS Under Credentials... I was under a project like that too. I will sending you the photo if need